# Accuracy calculation in multilabel classification

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, multilabel-classification

I'm using tensorflow on MSCOCO dataset which has 80 different classes and each image can contain more than one class (multilabels), this is modeled in my input as a list of 80 elements for each image, containing 1s at the right classes and 0s at he wrong classes.

I'm trying to calculate accuracy by checking the number of 1s in the predicted logits layer and comparing it element wise with the input true labels.

Using `tf.equal(logits , truelabels)` is not applicable because there are 80 classes with lots of zeros that are predicted correctly. So I end up with a high accuracy number and wrong predictions.

I tried to use `tf.map_fn` to break down the tensor into elements but apparently I can't use a counter like variable inside the function to choose the current true labels from a the true label batch (`Y_`).

here is my code:

```
rounded = tf.round(Y)
C = 0
V = 0
sumseen = 0.
sumtrue = 0.
avgg = 0.

def avgfunc(elm):
  global C
  global V
  global sumseen
  global sumtrue
  global avgg
  tru = Y_[C]
  ***tf.add(V,1)***
  cond1 = tf.count_nonzero(tf.cast(tf.equal(elm,tf.constant(1.,tf.float32)),tf.float32))
  cond2 = tf.count_nonzero(tf.cast(tf.equal(elm,tru[V]),tf.float32))
  if(cond1 == 1):
      sumseen+=1
      if(cond2 == 1):
          sumtrue+=1
  ***if(V >= 79):
      V = 0
      avgg = ((sumtrue/sumseen)*100) if sumseen !=0 else 0***
  return sumseen

def _comparefunc(elem_probs):
  global C
  tru = Y_[C]
  mapout = tf.map_fn(avgfunc, elem_probs)
  ***C = C+1
  if(C == 49):
      C = 0***
  return avgg

outputafter = tf.map_fn(_comparefunc, rounded)
accuracyofbatch = tf.reduce_mean(outputafter)
```

Comment: It's better to mark crucial lines in code by comments instead of *** - they might confuse the reader and make it harder to copy&paste the code to reproduce the problem.